# How to verify the absence of an element in an XML checkpoint

Tags: c#, xml, wpf

I have an application that is supposed to remove an element from an XML document.  So I want the checkpoint to pass if the tag is missing and fail if the tag is present.  How does one go about doing this?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you even looked at the [XmlDocument Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check an XML for the existence of a node using the [XmlDocument Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
using System.Xml.Linq;
...

var str = "Your XML";

XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(str);
var element = doc.Root.Element("NodeToCheck");

if ((element == null)) {
    Console.WriteLine("Checkpoint passed");
} else {
    Console.WriteLine(element.Value);
    Console.WriteLine("Checkpoint Failed");
}
```

This does assume that the node you are checking is at the root of the document.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple solutions for that. I would try getting it with an [XPath](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256471(v=vs.110).aspx) to get it.

You could also use a regex if you just want to know if there is a tag somewhere in the code.